# mvc application with razor data view engine problems with the url

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I create a new mhc application with razor data view engine. I have a problems with the url

Here is my action links

```
@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index")
@Html.ActionLink("Schedule", "Schedule")
```

After I loaded home page my url looks fine

Example: mysiteurl.com

Then I click Schedule link (if I hover I see the correct url http://mysiteurl.com/home/schedule). If I click it as a result my url  will http://mysiteurl.com//#/Home/Schedule. I don't know why its adding # sign to my url but it's causing the issue in my application with other pages.

any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Do you have any type of javascript attached to these links?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have an action method named Schedule? Can you successfully hit it by referencing yoursite.com/Home/Schedule? If not make sure your route is correct.